# Low-cost hotel/motel chains in Italy

Tags: budget, driving, hotels, italy

I will soon drive through the North in Italy and due to some unexpected events I will need to be back much earlier than expected. So I want to sleep somewhere along the way and I am trying to find a cheap hotel/motel.

I'm thinking about something like the French “Première classe” hotel chain, cheap (about €35 a night for this one but €40-45 would be fine) and basic but clean and functional. The rooms are the same everywhere, the experience is really bland and they are often located in business parks close to the motorway but all that is a plus in this case. These motels also allow round the clock (self-service) check-in, with a credit card.

Are there chains like that in Italy?

Comment: We drive semi-regularly from Florence to Verona to Hemingway country and Venice on the motorway with no hotel reservations at all.  There are always motel icons on the road signs and they are plentiful to the extent that advance planning isn't required. On the E70, you just take an exit, any exit and you'll find something. I can't see paying more than about EUR 30 - 40 except in the area around Trieste. Same thing goes for the trunk roads from Florence to Milan or Florence to Verona.

Comment: @GayotFow Thanks for the tip! Sounds like an answer to me, you could post it as one…

Comment: @Relaxed, in my answer, I would advise you that there are formulas and independents all along that road clustered at the slip roads.  I haven't made a reservation in Italy for yonks.  Same as the US also. Is that and my prior comment of any use such that it could be promoted to an answer?

Comment: In my whole life (I lived 27 years in Italy), I never saw a low-cost hotels-chain in Italy... If you don't want to spend a lot, you could try a B&B. They are usually very good

Comment: @Noldor130884 Yeah, I would generally do that for the stay itself but in this case I need to check in in the middle of the night (my goal is to go as far as possible to be closer to where I am going in the morning). I assumed it would not be possible for a B&B and, to be honest, I would feel bad about even asking a B&B owner something like that. But thanks for the info nonetheless.

Comment: @GayotFow Yes, I think it deserves to be promoted to an answer.

Comment: @Relaxed, well as we say in Italy "asking is always permitted"... Worst case, you get a "no, sorry"

Comment: @Relaxed, Joe (to whom a tip of the hat) has done better than I could do. The only thing I can add is use Google Maps to orient over where you are and then zoom to surface view and you will see the opportunities. Try it, it's fun!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### BB Hotels

The closest thing to the *Première Classe* hotel chain in Italy seems to be the BB Hotels chain. [There are 23 of these across Italy (mainly Northern Italy), mostly located close to the *Autostrada*](http://www.hotel-bb.com/it/hotel/italia.htm). Prices can be as cheap as those of *Première Classe* hotels, and, outside of manned reception opening hours, automated check-in is available.

### UNAWAY Hotels

Another option are [UNAWAY hotels](http://www.unawayhotels.it/it/cartina.htm), which are also scattered across Italy. Some of them are close to the Autostrada. Prices are more expensive than BB Hotels, and automatic/24-hour reception will depend on the hotel.

### Non-Franchise Hotels on the *Autostrada*

As @GayotFow points out, there are sometimes motels/hotels adjacent to *Autostrada* exits, and often these are advertised on the *Autostrada*. Luckily, [there is a website which allows you to search for them](http://www.hotelitaliaautostrade.com/). The best way to go about this is to use the drop-down menu on the right on the homepage (the rest of the website is definitely not designed for UX):

[image: Hotel Italia Autostrade website search using the drop-down menu]

If all that fails, try querying your favourite search engine for *motel autostrada*.

Comment: I found exactly what I needed using the info you provided, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The International Ibis chain is only a little above that, probably right there for their Budget line.

Comment: Yes, Ibis Budget hotels fit the bill and I didn't know Ibis was also present in Italy. Unfortunately, it seems they only have regular Ibis and Ibis Styles there (no Ibis Budget) but I see prices around €50, just a little over my target so that's definitely a useful suggestion, +1, thanks!